# Jquery on change to target only one form item

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a fiddle setup that calculate the price based on a select item but I only want the form it is in to be affected. At the moment if I select any drop down all values change.

http://jsfiddle.net/67jzyua5/

```js
    var basePrice = 12.99;
    $(".calculate").change(function() {
        newPrice = basePrice;
        $(".calculate option:selected").each(function() {
            newPrice += $(this).data('price')
        });
        $(".item-price").html(newPrice.toFixed(2));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="product_form" method="post" action="/product" class="product">
      <span>Apples</span>
      <select class="form-control calculate" id="product" name="product">
          <option data-price="1" value="1">1</option>
          <option data-price="2" value="2">2</option>
          <option data-price="3" value="3">3</option>
          <option data-price="4" value="4">4</option>
      </select>
      <br />                    
      <span class="item-price">12.99</span>
    </form>
```

I actually have this set up as a loop, product in forms, in the fiddle I have an example of how the HTML is output but I actually have it set up similar to this:

```
{% for product in forms %}
    {% include 'search/product.twig' with {'product': product} %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: to be honest ,I posted an answer but after re-reading your post many times I had a doubt, i did not understand what you want to do , do you want to multiply the selected value to the item-price value ? or to add it ? I want to post more a clear question please to be able to help you

Answer (score 1):

You need to scope down your selectors.  Currently they are global selectors.

```
var basePrice = 12.99;

$(".calculate").change(function(e) {
    //get the form the change happened in
    var $form = $(e.target).closest('form');

    newPrice = basePrice;

    //process only the calculate in this form
    $form.find(".calculate option:selected").each(function() {
        newPrice += $(this).data('price');
    });

    //change only the item price in this form
    $form.find(".item-price").html(newPrice.toFixed(2));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're displaying the newly calculated price to all classes named `item-price`, that's why it updates the price everywhere, use `$(this).nextAll('span')` to select the closest `span` and use `$(this).children(':selected').data('price')` to get the `data-price` of the selected option, `this` is referring to the current `.calculate` element :

```js
var basePrice = 12.99;

$(".calculate").change(function() {
    newPrice = basePrice;  
    newPrice += $(this).children(':selected').data('price');
    $(this).nextAll('span').html(newPrice.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="product_form" method="post" action="/product" class="product">
  <span>Apples</span>
  <select class="form-control calculate" id="product" name="product">
      <option data-price="1" value="1">1</option>
      <option data-price="2" value="2">2</option>
      <option data-price="3" value="3">3</option>
      <option data-price="4" value="4">4</option>
  </select>
  <br />                    
  <span class="item-price">12.99</span>
</form>

<form name="product_form" method="post" action="/product" class="product">
  <span>Pears</span>
  <select class="form-control calculate" id="product" name="product">
      <option data-price="1" value="1">1</option>
      <option data-price="2" value="2">2</option>
      <option data-price="3" value="3">3</option>
      <option data-price="4" value="4">4</option>
  </select>
  <br />                    
  <span class="item-price">5.00</span>
</form>

<form name="product_form" method="post" action="/product" class="product">
  <span>grapes</span>
  <select class="form-control calculate" id="product" name="product">
      <option data-price="1" value="1">1</option>
      <option data-price="2" value="2">2</option>
      <option data-price="3" value="3">3</option>
      <option data-price="4" value="4">4</option>
  </select>
  <br />                    
  <span class="item-price">16.99</span>
</form>
```